# Waterproofed water-temperature DS18B20 only returns -127 for degree in Celsius

Tags: arduino, sensors

For a project in university, I have to measure various quality of the water, including the temperature. The temperature sensor is DS18B20, and I use an Arduino Mega board to run the whole show. Individual running with DS18B20 only fails to return any meaningful number. Instead of 25C (or something like that), it returns -127.

The code below is from Dallas Temperature (with small changes, like having delay and removing some comment lines)

```
// Include the libraries we need
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into port 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 48

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);


void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Dallas Temperature IC Control Library Demo");

  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();
}

void loop(void)
{ 
  delay(500);
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperatures
  Serial.println("DONE");
  Serial.print("Temperature for the device 1 (index 0) is: ");
  Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));  
  delay(2500);
}
```

This one is actually from the [Wiki page of DFRobot](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__DS18B20_Temperature_Sensor__Arduino_Compatible__V2_SKU__DFR0024) (where my sensor is originated from)

```
#include <OneWire.h>

int DS18S20_Pin = 48; //DS18S20 Signal pin on digital 48

//Temperature chip i/o
OneWire ds(DS18S20_Pin);  // on digital pin 48

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  float temperature = getTemp();
  Serial.println(temperature);

  delay(100); //just here to slow down the output so it is easier to read
}

float getTemp(){
  //returns the temperature from one DS18S20 in DEG Celsius

  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];

  if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
      //no more sensors on chain, reset search
      ds.reset_search();
      return -1000;
  }

  if ( OneWire::crc8( addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
      Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
      return -1000;
  }

  if ( addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
      Serial.print("Device is not recognized");
      return -1000;
  }

  ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0x44,1); // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end

  byte present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0xBE); // Read Scratchpad


  for (int i = 0; i < 9;  i++  ) { // we need 9 bytes
    data[i] = ds.read();
  }

  ds.reset_search();

  byte MSB = data[1];
  byte LSB = data[0];

  float tempRead = ((MSB << 8) | LSB); //using two's compliment
  float TemperatureSum = tempRead / 16;

  return TemperatureSum;

}
```

This specific code returns -1000 every time, which I presume is the equivalence of -127 above.

Edit: The problem was identified as faulty electric wire. Yes, hardware problem.

Comment: Did you add a (4.7k) pull-up resistor between your DS18B20 pin and 5v?

Comment: Yes. Already did that. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the library:

```
// Error Codes
#define DEVICE_DISCONNECTED_C -127
```

https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library/blob/b34be08d603242bb534e7b717dac48baf60c5113/DallasTemperature.h#L36

So you're device is not connected / not communicating. Check your wiring and your pin numbers.

Comment: Everything is plugged in, yet for some reason, it is still not connected. I have even bought another DS18B20 (from another shop) but the result is still the same

Comment: did you use the correct pin numbers? maybe you confused pin 48 with digital in 48?

Comment: I was plugging the signal wire from the sensor into pin48 (which is a digital pin) on the Arduino Mega 2560. I have tried a few variants, but nothing changes. It looks like the sensor is not connected to the board (or the board does not recognise the sensor has been plugged in), the "-127" stands for "Device not connected"

Comment: ok now I'm confused. why would you explain to me that -127 stands for device not connnected? did you even read my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read that. -127 stands for Disconnected, not "Not connected". Still, I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I plug in the sensor into pin 48 digital on Arduino mega 48 (And I have tried on an UNO board, with adjusted pin number). Nothing changes.